# Attributes to backend in left column

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, backend

Suddenly something very strange happen. In Catalog-Attributes-Manage Attributes the content appear in left column. The main column is empty.
[image: Screenshot]

This happen only to Attributes.
There are 2 columns: "side-col" and "main-col". For some reason all data is "side-col".
I try to disable third-party extensions but nothing change.

Comment: any js errors in the console?

Comment: In Chrome no errors in console. But now I check Firefox and the console show me "unreachable code after return statement" in calendar.js:138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it will help.

Sometimes I had problems like this with broken translation files. It happens becasuse sometimes they breaks javascript strings.
No matter if you have the default Magento language on backend.

Try replacing them from a clean installation.
You can find them in "app/locale".

Comment: I have 2 languages installed. English and Greek. Try to change the display language in backend from lower-left of backend window but the problem is still there. I will try to update the English locale

Comment: Just to be sure. When you said you disabled extension, did you turned them off via backend or did you disalbe modules? Disableing from backend is almost useless, you should turn them off disabling config files in app/etc/modules.

Comment: I disabled through backend. I try to turnoff from app/etc/modules

Comment: FYI disabling from backend just turns off frontend output, it does not actually disable them.

Comment: Thank you Riccardo. You are so right. After turn off some modules specific to attributes I find the problem. Thank you.